# My code checks if a variable is nan. It is nan but somehow survives the check?

Tags: python, pandas

I am checking a pandas column: `df['email']`

There's only one row in this dataframe, and `df['email']` is simply an empty string: `''`

Anyway, this blank email is passing by the two checks below, and making it to the `do_other_stuff()` function, which causes an error. Because `nans` or empty strings are not supposed to get that far.

```
    email_address = df['email'].iloc[0]

    if email_address == '':
        df['email_format'] = 'Missing'
        return df

    elif email_address == np.nan:
        df['email_format'] = 'Missing'
        return df

    else:
        df['email_format'] = np.where(df[col].str.match(regex), 'Valid', 'Invalid')




AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!
```

I am checking the debugger in Vscode. I can see the `email_address` variable is `nan`.

[image]

However it still some how makes its way do `do_other_stuff()` ... what is going on here?

Strangely enough, if I pull the offending code out into a jupter notebook, it works fine...

The empty pandas row I'm playing with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'address1': 'hello world',
    'address2': '',
    'city': '',
    'county': '',
    'mobile': '',
    'email': '',
    'title': '',
    'firstname': '',
    'lastname': '',
    'gender': '',
    'dateofbirth': '',
    }, index=[0])
```

Comment: `np.nan == np.nan` => `False`

Comment: Change the `elif` condition to `elif email_address is np.nan:` -- as @superb rain noted, `np.nan == np.nan` resolves to `False`, so the current version skips the np.nan condition.

Answer (score 1):

`numpy.isnan(number)` tells you if it's `NaN` or not.

Comment: Even if it's not a number? I'm checking if `''` is nan.

Answer (score 1):

To check if it's a nan value, you can use
`pd.isna(email_address)`

Comment: `line 412, in email_format_checker
    if np.isnan(email_address):   TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''`

Comment: Oh, I thought `np.isnan`was working on str but it doesn't seem so. `pd.isna(email_address)` should work fine